# MATCH and INDEX into a matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-match

I did some research online regarding how to lookup values with two criteria. I found out it is done using `MATCH` and `INDEX`. But somehow I just can't make it work. I did press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Here's my formula:

```
=INDEX(Tables!$F$3:$G$6,MATCH(1,(D2=Tables!$E$3:$E$6)*(H2=Tables!$F$2:$G$2),0))
```

Example scenario is that I have a column called Entitled Discount.
I have `Gold`, `Silver` and `Bronze` Member. `Gold` has `5%` if buying `Product` but has `3%` if buying `Package`. `Silver` has `10%` if buying `Product` but has `4%` when buying `Package`:

```
 Membership     Package   Product 
   None            0%        0%
   Gold            3%        5%
   Silver          4%       10%
   Bronze          5%       15%
```

Comment: Since your formula is incorrect we need more info. You are trying to return  the correct percentage? Show an image of the worksheet, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is your data is laid out like so:

[image: SO33440999 example]

For which a formula such as:

```
=INDEX(E2:G6,MATCH(D2,E2:E6,0),MATCH(H2,E2:G2,0))
```

may suit.

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked !! And such a coincidence we are using the same cells too haha :)